# Does reactivating Fortification cancel the melee bonus?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The description for the Fortification ability is the following:

> Reinforce armor using protective Foucault currents. Purge the current
>   and send its charge to your gauntlets for increased melee damage.
>
> Slow down power use.

So deactivating (or "purging") Fortification gives you a melee damage bonus for certain duration.

My question is, if I immediately reactivate Fortification again to gain back the defensive bonus, do I then cancel the melee damage bonus that I just triggered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/377376-need-some-clarification-on-fortificaton/) on BioWare's forums, reactivating Fortification will not cancel the melee damage bonus, so you could immediately reactivate the ability to gain both bonuses:

> > The cooldown is 4 seconds.  So here's the scenario.  You deactivate
> >     Foritfication, wait the 4 seconds for cooldown and then reactivate, do
> >     you still have 16 seconds of 100% melee bonus damage and also get the
> >     benefits of shield regeneration and DR?
>
> Yes, thats how it works. Toggle it back and forth to have both the
>   damage buff and the shield.